# Can I add a Trust Anchor for a specific domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, dnssec

Some TLDs unfortunately still don't support DNSSEC all the way to the root.  However, is it possible to add a specific DNSKEY to my resolver (currently using `knot-resolver`) so that a signed zone can be verified even without TLD support?